# AutoMapper - Error mapping types for Enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper

I'm developing a web API with ASP.NET Core 6.
I am using the library Automapper.
When I try to convert my class DTO to my class of Entity, I receive an error,
because Automapper fails to recognize and convert enums.

The error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: CreateRequestUserDto -> User
> api.DTOs.CreateRequestUserDto -> api.Model.Entity.User
>
> Type Map configuration: CreateRequestUserDto -> User
> api.DTOs.CreateRequestUserDto -> api.Model.Entity.User
>
> Destination Member: Role
>
> ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map
> configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: EnumRoles -> Role api.Utilitis.Enum.EnumRoles ->
> api.Model.Entity.Role

Entity class User.cs:

```cs
namespace api.Model.Entity;
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other attributes
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Entity class Role.cs:

```cs
using api.Utilitis.Enum;
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Name", TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public EnumRoles Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

DTO class CreateRequestUserDto.cs:

```cs
using api.Utilitis.Enum;

namespace api.DTOs;
public class CreateRequestUserDto
{
    //other attributes
    public EnumRoles Role { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapperProfile.cs:

```cs
public AutoMapperProfile()
{
    CreateMap<User, CreateRequestUserDto>()
        .ForMember(cr => cr.Role, opt => opt.MapFrom(usr => usr.Role.Name)).ReverseMap();
    //other codes
}
```

Enum.cs:

```cs
namespace api.Utilitis.Enum;

public enum EnumRoles { 
    Administrator = 1, 
    Operator = 2 
}
```

UsersController.cs:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromForm] CreateRequestUserDto request)
{  
    var user = _mapper.Map<User>(request);
    var result = await _userService.CreateUser(user);
    return Ok(new { message = result.Message });
}
```

ServiceUser.cs:

```cs
public async Task<(bool Success, string Message)> CreateUser(User user)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Users.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();               

        return (true, "User added");

    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return (false, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What am I wrong?

Comment: `User.Role` is a class, not an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss out the mapping from `EnumRoles` to `Roles`.

Add a mapping from `EnumRoles` to `Roles` as below:

```cs
CreateMap<EnumRoles, Role>()
    .ConstructUsing((src, dest) => new Role { Id = (int)src });
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GLdZzL)

---

For inserting a duplicate entry for the `Role` issue, think that you need to query the `Role` by `Id`, then attach it to the `user`.

> ServiceUser.cs

```cs
public async Task<(bool Success, string Message)> CreateUser(User user)
{
    try
    {   
        var role = _context.Roles.Single(x => x.Id == user.Role.Id);
        user.Role = role;
 
        _context.Users.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();               

        return (true, "User added");

    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return (false, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: the mapping works fine, but creates a new record of Role when save User in context,
and catch exception:
 > MySqlException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'roles.PRIMARY'

Comment: Done update the answer. It's one of the way to avoid insert duplicate Role entry.